# TFS (VSTS) Stakeholder Work Item Creation Permission

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've allowed my Stakeholders to create Work Items but I would like to restrict them to only be able to create bugs and NOTHING else.  Currently they can create ANY Work Item type including Epics... I'm thinking there has to be a way to stop this but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting for this. And there is already a similar feature request submitted on VSTS User Voice: [Hide Work Item Types (WITs) based on permission/security group](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2085675-hide-work-item-types-wits-based-on-permission-se).